# Maximizing given expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$ with $-2\le x, y, z\le2$.

How can I get maximum of $${z(xy+xz+y)\over xy+y^2+z^2+1}$$

My attemt was to change $x, y, z$ to $2cosA, 2cosB, 2cosC$ with $A+B+C=\pi$. But it is not easy to take maximum of given form.

Comment: Are you sure that we can write $2.27882...$ in a nice form?

Comment: what is the source of this problem?